# Looping and setting global variables through a future function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, jcanvas

I got this section of code I can't seem to make work. It seems to be a scoping issue I was wondering if you have any idea.

Here is the section of code I think is broken.

```
                click: function(layer) {
                    selectedR = r;
                    selectedC = c;
                    render();
                },
```

The problem is when I click on the image it executes the function, however the values for selectedR/selectedC are always getting set to 8,8 which implies it isn't grabbing the variable value from r,c until the function is actually clicked. Can you think of a way I can accomplish this? I basically want to know the r,c of the item I click on. I am using JQuery/JCanvas libraries if that helps. Below is the code in context.

```
var selectedR;
var selectedC;


function drawPieces(){
    for( var r = 0; r < 8; r++){
        for(var c = 0; c < 8; c++){
            var x = boardLeft + (c * tileWidth);
            var y = boardTop + (r * tileHeight);
            var piece = gameboard[r][c];

            if(piece.pieceCode == ChessPieceEnum.EMPTY){
                continue;
            }

            $("canvas").drawImage({
                layer: true,
                source: piece.pieceCode.normalImage,
                x: x, 
                y: y,
                cursor: "pointer",
                click: function(layer) {
                    selectedR = r;
                    selectedC = c;
                    render();
                },
                fromCenter: false
            });

            piece.x = x;
            piece.y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The famous `i` looping problem

Comment: This is an instance of an extremely common problem in JavaScript. It's effectively a duplicate of dozens (if not hundreds) of similar questions :-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! Sorry I am fairly new to Javascript and wasn't sure what to search for. Sorry for the Dup!

Answer (score 0):

So it appears the layer object that is passed into the click functions is a reference to itself. So just add r/c to the layer object than you have access to it in the anonymous function.

```
function drawPieces(){
    for( var r = 0; r < 8; r++){
        for(var c = 0; c < 8; c++){
            var x = boardLeft + (c * tileWidth);
            var y = boardTop + (r * tileHeight);
            var piece = gameboard[r][c];

            if(piece.pieceCode == ChessPieceEnum.EMPTY){
                continue;
            }

            $("canvas").drawImage({
                layer: true,
                source: piece.pieceCode.normalImage,
                x: x, 
                y: y,
                r: r,
                c: c,
                cursor: "pointer",
                click: function(layer){
                    onPieceClick(layer.r, layer.c);
                },
                fromCenter: false
            });

            piece.x = x;
            piece.y = y;
        }
    }
}

function onPieceClick(r,c){
    selectedR = r;
    selectedC = c;
    render();
}
```